# Running retention policy against folders

Tags: workflow, 2016, folder, library, retention

I have retention enabled for folders. It is set to run a workflow on any folder after it is a day old. and to run it once a day. However it doesn't appear to be working. I have both the "Information management policy" and "Expiration policy" time jobs set to one day. Is it even possible to run retention against folders?

[image]

Comment: did you ran the both Information management and expirtion timer jobs? if yes what order ?

Comment: they are both set to run at midnight daily, i waited over night. I did not manualy run the timer jobs.

Comment: However, if I do run the timer jobs manually, what is the proper procedure?

Comment: You have to execute the “Information management policy” job first, once completed successfully then run "Expiration policy” job.

Comment: Thank you so much. It didn't execute the first night for some reason but did the second, wonder if because I have them set to run at the same time, if that caused an issue. Would staggering the timer jobs so that "information management policy" definately runs first be beneficial?

Comment: jobs should be run in order otherwise it will cause the issue. Information job 1st followed by expiration, make sure 1st completed then 2nd will start.....So, after running in order, did it work as expected or you are still testing?

Comment: I can't choose answer for anything you have typed for some reason.

Comment: You can't here, but I added it as answer so you can go ahead mark it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks the timer jobs not running in order, by default they are in order. But as you change the schedule,
Could you please make sure that

1. Information Management policy timer jobs run 1st.
2. Onece the above job completed then exipration policy job should started

If above sequence not followed then it will not work.